# Carbon diffForHumans not displaying the date

Tags: php, php-carbon

As the title says I'm trying to use Carbon's diffForHumans but the output only ever returns `ago` or `before`. I'm not using it as part of any framework just adding it standalone to my project.

Here's the code I'm using to test it, that should work just fine.

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

echo "<pre>";

$dt = Carbon::createFromDate(2011, 8, 1);
echo $dt->diffForHumans($dt->copy()->addMonth());   // 1 month before
echo $dt->diffForHumans($dt->copy()->subMonth());   // 1 month after

echo "</pre>";
```

Actual output is `beforeafter`.
composer.lock shows I'm using version 2.50.0 and I'm using php version 7.2.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

symfony/translation v4.4.27 broke initial translations for Carbon, upgrade nesbot/carbon to >= 2.51.0.

Comment: `Carbon::getLocale()` returns `en` I checked the directory and I do have all the language files. Forcing `en_CA` actually did work so I guess the en file is broken for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: You likely hit the breaking change introduced by symfony/translation v4.4.27 but it's compatible again upgrading to nesbot/carbon 2.51.0.

Comment: Can confirm updating has fixed this issue.